# How to modify IIS role services in Windows Server 2012?

Tags: windows-server-2012, graphical-user-interface, windows, iis-8

I have a clean Windows Server 2012 installation.  I installed the Web Server (IIS) role, and during the process it asked me which Role Services I would like (asp.net, iis6 metabase compatibility, etc.).

How do I get back to this screen to add or remove *role services*?  In the server manager, if I go to the IIS tab, I can see the services under *Roles and Features*, but then only option appears to be adding or removing entire *roles*.  I don't want to uninstall IIS, I just want to add or remove another role service within the IIS role.

The Add/Remove Roles and Features wizard disables the `Next` button if you aren't modifying any roles - so you can't ever get to the role services page for the roles you already have.

**UPDATE**

I figured out how to do it from powershell by following the instructions [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831809.aspx#BKMK_installwps).  Basically:

```
Install-WindowsFeature -Name <feature name>
```

The list of feature names is returned with:

```
Get-WindowsFeature
```

It seems that there is not a distinction between feature names for roles or role services when it comes to the powershell scripts.  But the GUI makes a distinction somehow.

I would still like to know how to get back to the role services selection from the GUI.

Comment: Why not uninstall it and install it again with the options you want?

Comment: @HopelessN00b - Because that would be extremely counterproductive.  I have already installed and configured the rest of IIS as I want it, and I don't want to redo all that work.  This was very easy under Win2008/IIS7.  I don't understand why it would be any different in Win2012/IIS8.  Also - what if the site was live already?  I shouldn't have to completely uninstall the web server just to change some options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to Server Manager, or type "servermanager" at a command prompt.  The GUI Server Manager will pop up.

Click the Manage dropdown up in the top right. Choose "Add Roles and Features."

Click next, next, select the right server, click next.

Now you should be on the Server Roles selection.  Expand IIS (which will be greyed out since you have already installed it.)  But the features or role services or whatever you want to call them, such as WebDAV Publishing for example, will not be greyed out because you haven't installed it yet.  So click it.

Hit next, next, Install.  Add and remove role services at will.

Please find the Screenshot:

[image: ScreenShotForManageOptions]

Comment: OK, I feel dumb.  I had to expand out the grayed-out "Web Server (Installed)", and the grayed-out "Application Development (Installed)" and then I see the rest of the services I was looking for.  Note that this is not the path that occurred when I first added the Web Server role, so I think that's what threw me off.

Comment: No problem... I was afraid to submit the answer at first because I thought I must be missing something obvious that would get me downvotes. :)

Answer (score 1):

To remove webdav use the following Powershell command:

uninstall-windowsfeature -name web-dav-publishing